# prepare stmt line thorws error

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, ms-access-2010, prepared-statement

need help on this simple task.
this sp should deliver a resultset and will called from within an MS-Access-Database reporting purposes.

The tablename is vvarying, but it is ending on a number (lsid). Concatenatoin is used.
max_prepared_statement_count is on default-value 16382

Any good ideas?

thx
Thomas

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root2`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp_Quickview02`(IN lsid int)
BEGIN
set @tbl = concat('shape_tokens_',lsid); -- tablename

set @sql= 'select base.Status, count(base.token) as Anzahl 
                    from (select ?.completed, if(?.completed = ''N'',''offen'', ''abgeschlossen'') as Status,
            ?.token from ?) base group by base.status;'

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql; -- error is thrown here
EXECUTE stmt using @tbl;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check your variable @sql value then it will provide you below ouput, which can't execute, so correct it.

```
SELECT base.Status, COUNT(base.token) AS Anzahl 
                    FROM (SELECT ?.completed, IF(?.completed = 'N','offen', 'abgeschlossen') AS STATUS,
            ?.token FROM ?) base GROUP BY base.status;
```

change as per below-

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root2`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp_Quickview02`(IN lsid int)
BEGIN
set @tbl = concat('shape_tokens_',lsid); -- tablename

SET @sql= CONCAT('select base.Status, count(base.token) as Anzahl 
                    from (select a.completed, if(a.completed = ''N'',''offen'', ''abgeschlossen'') as Status,
            a.token from ',@tbl,' as a) base group by base.status;');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql; -- error is thrown here
EXECUTE stmt using @tbl;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Query is expecting 4 parameter so use execute query as given below:

```
EXECUTE stmt using @tbl, @tbl, @tbl, @tbl;
```